# How to stop select tag helper from automatically adding 'multiple' attribute

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm working in `.Net Core VS2017`

and trying to populate my dropdown with data from the model. For this purpose I declared my select list as

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="TicketTypes" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.TicketTypes,"Id","Name"))"></select>
```

It is loading the data correctly but it automatically adds the multiple attribute to it. How to stop this because I need to show this in dropdown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out the select tag helper will automatically generate a multi-select if the property specified in the asp-for attribute is an IEnumerable.

```
public IEnumerable<Models.TicketTypeList> TicketTypes { get; set; }
```

So I changed the code and stored the data in `ViewBag` as `SelectList` by changing the code in controller to

```
var ticketTypes = _context
                .TicketType
                .Where(w => w.Deleted == false)
                .Select(s => new {
                                                    id = s.Id,
                                                    Name = s.Name
                    }).OrderBy(o=>o.Name).ToList();

ViewBag.ticketTypeList = new SelectList(ticketTypes, "id", "Name");
```

and then in the view changed the code to

```
@Html.DropDownList("TicketTypes",ViewBag.ticketTypeList as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```