# Can't create a dropdown using Select TagHelper but scaffolding does

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I used scaffolding to get a simple MVC page and it produced code like this from my model:

```
ViewData["CustomersNo"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "CustomersId", "Name");
```

Then I scaffolded the view which produced markup like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="CustomersNo" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select asp-for="CustomersNo" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CustomersNo"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And when rendered it produced a dropdown control with my customers from my database. Exactly what I wanted and I didn't even have to write a line of code.

But now I want to create a dropdown on a more customized view using filtered data. No matter what I do, it renders as a multiselect which I definitely do not want.

I want to use a View Model but I've also tried ViewData since that is what the scaffolding used:

```
proViewModel.Vols = new SelectList(_context.Products.Where(t => t.Type == "Volume"), "ModelId", "ModelId");
ViewData["VolModels"] = new SelectList(_context.Products.Where(t => t.Type == "Volume"), "ModelId", "ModelId");
```

My View Model is pretty simple so far:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    //public IEnumerable<string> Vols { get; set; }
    //public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Vols { get; set; }
    public SelectList Vols { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string SelectedModel { get; set; }
}
```

I tried different `IEnumerable` types since that was what most tutorials used. But the scaffolding uses `SelectList` and [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427891/how-to-stop-select-tag-helper-from-automatically-adding-multiple-attribute) as well as this [tutorial](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc6-select-tag-helper.aspx) both say that `IEnumerable` will create a multiselect and seem to suggest using `SelectList`.

But with this markup, all I can get is multiselect:

```
<td>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Vols" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="Vols" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.Vols"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Vols" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="Vols" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.VolModels"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

I can't see a difference between what the scaffolding is doing and what I am doing. But the rendered output is completely different and not what I want. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects, which is what `Vols` is. A `<select>` binds to, and posts back a simple type and a `<select multiple>` binds to, and posts back an array of a simple type.

In addition, the name of the property your binding to and the name of the `SelectList` cannot be the same (refer [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist/37162557#37162557) for more detail).

Because the property your binding to is `IEnumerable`, a `<select multiple>` is created.

Change your code to

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SelectedModel" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select asp-for="SelectedModel" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.Vols"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the selected option value will be bound to the `SelectedModel` property.

As a side note, remove your `[Key]` and `[NotMapped]` attributes - they a EF specific attributes and have no place in a view model.

Comment: Added those attributes a few days ago to get past some compile errors. I didn't think they belonged either. No problems now. Don't know what I did elsewhere to fix that.

Comment: As another side note, I would also recommend making your property `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Vols { get; set; }` - `SelecList` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` but not the other way around (that then gives you the flexibility of using `_context.Products.Where(...).Select(x => new SelectListItem{ ... });` or `new SelectList(_context.Products.Where(...).Select(x => x.ModelId));`

Comment: Got it. Was wondering why every example was `IEnumerable`. Makes sense if it's more flexible.

Comment: I must have just compiled and not run last night. If I delete the `[Key]` or `[NotMapped]` attributes, when I run but after I log in I get, "The entity type 'SelectListGroup' requires a primary key to be defined" and points to the line in `public async Task<IActionResult> Index()` where I pull the contents of a table into a variable before passing it to a view. Am I missing some step in defining it as a view model as opposed to an EF model?

Comment: It sounds like your associating your view model with EF. View models should not be in your `/Models` folder. They need to be in a separate folder (say) `/ViewModels`

Comment: Okay. I'll try that tomorrow. The scaffolding put its own view models in sub-folders under `/Models`. So I followed suit. Guess I need to follow the tutorials more closely instead of trying to imitate the scaffolding.